# Pandas dataframe: selecting max by column for subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Am fairly new to pandas and going around in circles trying to find an easy way to solve the following problem:

I have a large correlation matrix (several thousand rows / columns) as a dataframe and would like to extract the maximum value by column excluding the '1' which is of course present in all columns (diagonal of the matrix).

Tried all sorts of variations of .max() .imax(), including the following:

```
corr.drop(corr.idxmax()).max()
```

But only get nonsense results. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use np.fill_diagonal

```
df_values=df.values.copy()
np.fill_diagonal(df_values,-np.inf)
df_values.max(0)
```

Or with a one-liner you can use:

```
df.values[~np.eye(df.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(df.shape[0]-1,-1).max(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the 2nd highest values from each column.

As array:

```
np.partition(df.values, len(df)-2, axis=0)[len(df)-2]
```

or in a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.partition(df.values, len(df)-2, axis=0)[len(df)-2],
             index=df.columns, columns=['2nd'])
```